# Rendering freehand drawn geometry from geojson on map with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I want to render freehand drawn geometry from a geojson object on a map. I have the freehand drawing all set up and working. The geometry is `LineString` but I am adding the `freehand: true` property which works. Now   after getting the coordinates on 'drawend' event using

```
var shape = event.feature.getGeometry();
var coords = shape.getCoordinates();
```

I am saving the coordinates e.g [[-1.213123, 3.123123], [0.213123, 2.2312123]], so I can load it later.

To render it, I am doing the following

```
        var geojsonObject = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'crs': {
                'type': 'name',
                'properties': {
                    'name': 'EPSG:3857'
                }
            },
            'features': [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'LineString',
                    'coordinates': [[-1.213123, 3.123123], [0.213123, 2.2312123]],
                    'freehand': true
                }
            }]
        };

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject),
        });
```

to get my vector source, but it renders as an actual lineString instead of a drawn lineString. Any ideas?